# error in foreman start for heroku during deploying rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, heroku-toolbelt

I try to getting start with Rails 3.2.6 and Heroku. My Ruby version is 1.9.3 and my database.yml is like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: iscubeonror_development
  pool: 5
  username: rails
  password: rails
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: iscubeonror_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: iscubeonror_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

my procfile is as

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
```

I have on production.rb, on development.rb and on test.rb this:

```
 config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
 config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
 config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
```

Finaly I am using windows and my Gemfile is

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
gem 'pg'
gem 'thin'
gem "foreman"
```

when write on terminal **heroku logs** it gives me warnig as

```
2012-11-20T18:05:32+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-st
yle plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rail
s 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your ap
p as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes f
or more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been
-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-11-20T18:05:32+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-st
yle plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rail
s 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your ap
p as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes f
or more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been
-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-11-20T18:05:35+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-11-20T18:05:35+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Thin
2012-11-20T18:05:35+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.6 application starting in pro
duction on http://0.0.0.0:52284
2012-11-20T18:05:35+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
```

when write on terminal **foreman start** It gives me as

```
D:\Kalpesh\web\iscubeonror> foreman start
19:37:27 web.1  | started with pid 3868
19:38:18 web.1  | You did not specify how you would like Rails to report depreca
tion notices for your $RACK_ENV environment, please set config.active_support.de
precation to :log, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/$RACK_ENV.rb
```

due to this my thin server is not started what should i do
though i follow all steps from 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3#deploy-your-application-to-heroku
plz urgent reply me

Comment: possible duplicate of [error during deploy rails application on heroku in forman start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486307/error-during-deploy-rails-application-on-heroku-in-forman-start)

Comment: please add your procfile

Comment: i am not using add procfile in application.

Comment: but where do you specify what is foreman starting

Comment: is it necessary to specify foreman start even if not using procfile?

Comment: k. then where it should be specify ?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#process-types-as-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read:

```
You did not specify how you would like Rails to report depreca
tion notices for your $RACK_ENV environment, please set config.active_support.de
precation to :log, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/$RACK_ENV.rb
```

Comment: you should read the question ;) quote:

"I have on production.rb, on development.rb and on test.rb this:

 config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
 config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
 config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr"

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to define some env vars in .env as :

```
RACK_ENV=development
PORT=3000
```